# form_authenticity_token undefined ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Trying to implement a angularjs ruby on rails app...

I get this error when I try to embed an authenticity token into my angularjs form like so:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
```

I get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `form_authenticity_token' for #<#<Class:0x00000005953418>:0x007fcdc1205b20>
```

I would really like to be able to include the authenticity token in my angularjs forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[form_authenticity_token](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/form_authenticity_token) is only accessible in the Controllers, but NOT in Views. You are getting that mentioned error because you are trying to use that in your view.

You can define an instance variable in the corresponding controller's action like this:

```
# in controller
def your_action
  @form_auth_token = form_authenticity_token
end
```

And, then use `@form_auth_token` in your view:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, @form_auth_token %>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of afraid something like this would be the answer! In the end I took your advice, declared an instance variable, then initialized an scope.instance with json_encoded array of auth code. Works perfectly, although it's a a bit of a work around.